# Ionic 2 - Google Maps Native: marker click event not firing

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and the [google maps cordova plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps).

"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.0.11"

I cannot get this listener to fire.

The marker is added to the map but the click event does not fire the alert.

Thanks for the help!

```
    let latlng = new LatLng(spot.lat, spot.long);
    let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        'position': latlng,
        'animation': 'drop'
      };


      this.map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: Marker) => {
        marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(e => {
          alert('foo');
        });
      });
```

Additional Information

`@ionic-native/core: 'version': 3.7.0`

`@ionic-native/google-maps: 'version': '4.3.0'`

`import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapOptions,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 LatLng,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';`

I am looping through multiple `lat` `long` coordinates and adding them to the map. The event never gets fired for any of them.

When I try to attach the even to just one of the markers it does not work either.

Lastly if I put another alert it does not fire. Is it possible the add marker promise is not resolving?

```
this.map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: Marker) => {
   alert('in here'); 
 marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(e => {
   alert('foo');
 });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What versions of `@ionic-native/core` and `@ionic-native/google-maps` do you use? At least the above code should work.

Comment: @wf9a5m75 I have added additional information. Thanks for the help. I think it should work, not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

You should try this. It worked fine for me

```
marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe((latLng: LatLng) => {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you have posted does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@ionic-native/core@4.4.0` and `@ionic-native/google-maps@4.4.0`. 
At least `@ionic-native/core@3.7.0` is too old.

```
$> npm uninstall @ionic-native/core @ionic-native/google-maps
$> cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-googlemaps

$> npm install @ionic-native/core@latest @ionic-native/googlemaps@latest
$> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..." --no-fetch
```

From the `@ionic-native/google-maps@4.4.0`, the way of creating a map is changed.

```
export class HomePage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor() {  // <-- no longer need to define in constructor
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');  // <-- changed
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Still no luck. grrrr. The map is created and the markers are on the map but still no click event.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how you would add a marker to the map? Does it have to be in the `one` function? I currently am loading the markers each time the camera stops moving.

Comment: Could you read the document site at once before asking? https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/class/BaseArrayClass/constructor/README.md

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Thanks yeah Ive read this documentation many times. Its still not clear to me what I am doing wrong. Seems to work for everyone but me and there are plenty of examples of it working https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/1790 Ill just keep banging my head against the wall. Thanks for your help Ill let you know what I had to do